# Pull ssh-client container via docker-compose

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to *Docker* and may not understand something.

I have an `app` container and a `dockerfile`.

I want to install an `ssh-client` into the `app` container. 
I want to be able to run `ssh` command to reach some external ip from the `app` container.

The simplest way I know is to add

`RUN apk update && apk add openssh-client bash`

to my `dockerfile`, but I'd like to use some ready image, so all my containers could use the same one.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search over dockerhub where all the public images reside, you will find that all the "ssh-client" popular images there are simply building on top of alpine and installing `openssh-client` exactly that way you described it.

So there is no obvious benefit in using those existing images. Just install the ssh-client via:

```
RUN apk update && apk-install openssh-client
```

Comment: But do I understand correctly, that I can save space via images? For example, I have 20 projects containers, that need `ssh`. If I'll install via `RUN apk update && apk-install openssh-client`, than It will take 20 times more space, that somehow used pulled image? Do I get it right? If so, than saving space is very important to me.

Comment: @D.R. When u say 20 projects I understand you mean 20 containers. Now each container has to be totally selfcontained. So the ssh-client has to be installed in each app container if u need it. Now Docker has a nice feature which is layer caching. If you use the same base image and then install ssh-client after it directly in all containers, then the same layer will be used and ssh-client will only be downloaded once and installed in a layer that will be shared by all other images.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I understand you right, I should keep an eye on the order of my commands inside the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @D.R. Yes. As docker file best practices, you should avaoid what is called cache invalidation. Read more about Dockerfile best practices https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll accept it, if @Simon Schürg won't help with `docker-compose` compose example. I understand, that this is a simple one, but I could need to install something more complex in the future. I'd like to be able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Write a `Dockerfile` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

```
FROM alpine:latest
# install ssh-client and bash
RUN apk --no-cache add openssh-client bash
# example ssh usage to print version
ENTRYPOINT ["ssh", "-V"]
```

Build and run it with: `docker build -t ssh . && docker run -t ssh ssh`
Or use Docker-Compose.

After building with `docker build` you can reuse the ssh Docker image in your other projects in Dockerfiles.

```
FROM ssh
...
```

Using Docker-Compose `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ssh:
    build: .
    image: ssh
```

You can add multiple services in the compose file as you like.
The docker compose file from above uses the Dockerfile from above to build your ssh docker image.
See the compose file reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: Yes, I'm using docker-compse with 3 services. app, db and server. Could you show an example with docker-compose?)

Comment: Thank you, but could you show how to connect it to my app, so I could run `ssh` inside the app container? I can show you my `docker-compose.yml` if you need it.